# Tensorflow Object Detection API bounding box coordinates

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm using the Tensorflow Object Detection API to recognize backpacks and suitcases, and am running into a problem when attempting to isolate one bounding box. I'm running the basic object_detection_app.py from the Github and I need the coordinates/size of each box, which I have found in the array called boxes. Here is the relevant code for the boxes numpy array

```
boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
...
   # Actual detection.
(boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
    [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

# Visualization of the results of a detection.
flattened_boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image_np,
    flattened_boxes,
    np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
    np.squeeze(scores),
    category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    line_thickness=8)
#print(flattened_boxes)
return image_np
```

I added the flattened_boxes variable so that I didn't have to squeeze twice when trying to reference the boxes array. When I print the array, currently commented out, I get a large output that is expected based on the outcome of the visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array function (an Nx4 numpy array).

```
[[ 0.19599476  0.2981517   0.99717104  0.82842588]
 [ 0.41137621  0.64978909  0.50763148  0.69665825]
 [ 0.43020707  0.74842983  0.4897657   0.78688926]
 [ 0.42019451  0.6926229   0.50535047  0.7341491 ]
 [ 0.43565691  0.64267403  0.52299386  0.68705386]
 [ 0.66776097  0.75630403  0.76703691  0.79438317]
 [ 0.42019451  0.6926229   0.50535047  0.7341491 ]
```

I would like to reference a single row of the array to get the coordinates of a single box, but when I try to print flattened_boxes[0,0], no output is printed.  I have tried to print the shape of the array, which will not print either. Why can't I use [0,0] to reference a single element of this array?

Comment: So `print(flattened_boxes[0,0])` and `print(flattened_boxes.shape)` aren't giving you errors?  How about `print(type(flattened_boxes))`?  It seems really odd that you're not getting anything printed.  Are you sure those lines are being executed, and you're calling `print`?

Comment: I have tried all three of those, and I get no output and no errors. The program runs as if they aren't there. When I just print flattened_boxes, it outputs what I have shown.